# How to get the KDE proxy settings

Tags: linux, ubuntu, opensuse, kde-plasma

For Gnome, we use `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.system.proxy` to get the proxy related configuration.

> How to fetch the Proxy configuration of a KDE desktop with
> kwriteconfig.I believe kwriteconfig is only for setting the KDE
> configuration. Please let me know if we have any command which help us
> to get the proxysettings.

Answer (score -1):

> kreadconfig is a command-line tool to retrieve values from KDE
> configuration files.